# Configuring globally installed eslint

Tags: javascript, npm, visual-studio-code, eslint

I installed globally eslint@4.2.0 and wanted to use some predefined configs. When I tried to install `eslint-config-google` it said that I don't have eslint>=4.1.0 (which I had of course, but installed globaly). The same problem occured when installing `eslint-config-airbnb-base` - ultimately predefined configs can't see globally installed eslint (and even `eslint --init` can't see it cause it installed another instance of eslint locally when I run it). Then I decided to install both eslint and configuration files locally, in my projects directory - works like a charm, but still I'd like to have these things in global scope so I wouldn't have to care about it each time I make a new directory for my projects.
Is it possible to make eslint and predifined configs work at global scope or at least have global eslint and local configuration file?

Comment: Honestly, I'd recommend keeping it all local to each project. Then you don't have to worry about breaking changes and changing config options all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ultimately predefined configs can't see globally installed eslint

Actually, they can. Or rather, global ESLint can use global configs. It just doesn't know how to cross the barrier between global and local.

> Then I decided to install both eslint and configuration files locally, in my projects directory - works like a charm

Good choice. This is going to be crucial when you eventually have projects with conflicting needs.

> but still I'd like to have these things in global scope so I wouldn't have to care about it each time I make a new directory for my projects

That is what project scaffolding tools like [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) are for. Here is the one I use, [generator-seth](https://github.com/sholladay/generator-seth).

Whenever I start a new project, I simply type `seth` and answer a couple of questions and it's done with glorious magic under the hood.

> Is it possible to make eslint and predifined configs work at global scope or at least have global eslint and local configuration file?

Yepp. You can have a local `.eslintrc` file and the global ESLint will respect it. You can run `eslint --init` to set this up (that will also install ESLint locally, but you don't need to use it).

But an even better way is to use [XO](https://github.com/sindresorhus/xo), which is built on top of ESLint (and supports all ESLint rules). Unlike ESLint, XO knows how to automatically choose the appropriate installation to use. You can install it both locally and globally and its global CLI will defer to the local copy when one is detected. This is important because it means that each project can keep its own version of the linter while still allowing you to run XO globally. So if a breaking change comes out, your projects are not screwed all at once or broken when they have conflicting needs. The configuration for XO is kept locally either way, so unlike ESLint you do not have duplicate local and global configs.

Comment: Wow, that's really helpful, thank you very much! I'm quite new to Javascript and honestly have never heard of these things, but I feel they'll help me a lot in the future. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I have recently encountered the same issue, here is my solution (OS: Windows):

First, I run eslint initial command to configure my preference:

```
$ eslint --init
```

> ? How would you like to use ESLint? **To check syntax, find problems, and enforce code style**
>   ? What type of modules does your project use? **CommonJS (require/exports)**
>   ? Which framework does your project use? **None of these**
>   ? Where does your code run? **Browser, Node**
>   ? How would you like to define a style for your project? **Use a popular style guide**
>   ? Which style guide do you want to follow? **Airbnb (https://github.com/airbnb/javascript)**
>   ? What format do you want your config file to be in? **JavaScript**
>   Checking peerDependencies of eslint-config-airbnb-base@latest
>   The config that you've selected requires the following dependencies:
>
> eslint-config-airbnb-base@latest eslint@^4.19.1 || ^5.3.0 eslint-plugin-import@^2.17.2
>   ? Would you like to install them now with npm? **No**

Second, I copy the "**.eslintrc.js**" file that eslint generated locally into my user home directory (C:\Users\username) to make it a global configuration file.

Finally, I use npm to install the required packages **globally**:

```
npm install -g  eslint@^5.16.0 eslint-config-airbnb-base eslint-plugin-import
```

> ***Important***
>
> Don't use `npm install -g eslint` because it will install the latest **eslint** version
>   (like 6.0.1) and therefore, the dependencies of **eslint-config-airbnb-base** and **eslint-plugin-import** will go wrong

And here is the article you may find more information if you want configure differently [How to globally set up eslint in vscode](https://medium.com/@davidchristophersally/how-to-set-up-eslint-in-vscode-globally-253f25fbaff9).